# 'QVCI feature is disabled' ERROR when using existing Teradata Database to define models for use by flask app

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, odbc, teradata

In attempting to build my flask application around an existing Teradata Database, I have run into an issue defining the db models to be used by my application from this existing database. I am getting sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (9719, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseQVCI feature is disabled.'). I am using teradata version 16.20 and it appears that the QVCI feature has been disabled in this newest version.

I have been able to successfully make a connection to a Teradata Database using both sqlalchemy and pyodbc through my flask application. So the problem is not in making the initial connection. Where I am struggling is to build my flask application around the existing database that I have already been able to connect to. I have some example code I was able to find based on another question that I was expecting would take my 'users_table' and make it usable as the Class 'Users' to my flask application. However, when trying to have sqlalchemy retrieve the 'users_table', teradata tells me that the QVCI feature has been disabled. Here is the code I was able to find that resulted in the error:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- mode: python -*-

from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

user = 'user_string'
pasw='password_string'
host = 'host_string'

engine = create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host + '/' + '?authentication=LDAP', convert_unicode=True, echo=False)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.reflect(engine)


from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, bckref

class Users(Base):
    __table__ = Base.metadata.tables['users_table']


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, Query
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
    for item in db_session.query(Users.id, Users.name):
        print(item)
```

After running, I get the sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (9719, '[HY000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseQVCI feature is disabled.'). Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same issue using the [sqlalchemy-teradata](https://github.com/Teradata/sqlalchemy-teradata) dialect for sqlalchemy. For me, it was enough to switch over to [teradatasqlalchemy](https://pypi.org/project/teradatasqlalchemy/). It seems that the first is not being developed actively anymore. The second is officially supported by Teradata and is under active development. So I guess it's the way to go anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any specific knowledge of QVCI, but from what I've gleaned from a little online browsing is that it's a database-level feature that you may be able to enable/disable:

http://knowledge.teradata.com/support/general/kcs.nsf/id/KCS018468

Check your dbscontrol flags to see if there is an option to enable it.  Here's a link that may help:

https://docs.teradata.com/reader/3v9n8mulIn_WRhsXpj609w/VEc7SwG43uPE51o9QiodPQ

If you see a flag in one of the sections and it's disabled, try enabling it.  I think you'll need to "modify" and then "write" to the dbscontrol (and possibly restart the DBS) for the changes to take effect.

**Update**
Another option is to update your client TD driver to the latest version.  It looks like there were some bug fixes related to QVCI:

https://teradata-docs.s3.amazonaws.com/doc/connectivity/tdnetdp/16.20/help/WhatsNew16000000.html

Answer (score 0):

QVCI should *not* be enabled at this time. Upgrade the Teradata driver you are using (which appears to be ODBC, in this case) to the latest patch level, which tolerates this condition.

You could also consider using the teradatasqlalchemy module and teradatasql dialect, which do not require Teradata ODBC or pyodbc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, @Fred. Allow me to address each of these suggestions separately: 

1.) My understanding is that the connection engine created by sqlalchemy does NOT need a driver defined in the connection string like above. Is there a parameter to manually set a driver in the connection string?

2.) So I did try to use the teradatasqlalchemy module and teradatasql dialect, however, it looks as if the parameter 'database' is not implemented.....at least not yet. What I should have mentioned in my question is that I would like to set a default database in my connection string.

Comment: You need not specify a driver unless you have multiple versions of Teradata ODBC installed and the `teradata:` dialect is defaulting to the wrong one. But yes, you can append a `driver=_theDriverName_` to the connection string. You are correct that teradatasql does not yet support setting a default database as part of the connection string.

Comment: The `teradata` module / dialect relies on the "OS native" Teradata ODBC Driver which must be separately installed on the client.

Comment: So I have this as my new connection string 

```python


engine = create_engine('teradata://'+ user +':' + pasw + '@'+ host + '/db_name' + '?authentication=LDAP&driver=Teradata Database ODBC Driver 16.20', convert_unicode=True, echo=False)``` where 'db_name' is the name of my default database. However, using this connection string with the Driver 16.20, I still get the same error that 'QVCI feature is disabled'. Am I missing something? Thanks.

Comment: I should have been more specific. You were already picking up the 16.20 driver by default. The problem is the specific maintenance / fix / patch level of the 16.20 driver that is installed. (For example, 16.20.00.01 would have this problem.) You will need to upgrade to a more recent level - so might as well go with the most current one for your client OS.

Comment: One other note regarding teradatasqlalchemy / teradatasql: You can't set default database at the engine (connection string) level but you can set it at connection level (execute a DATABASE statement) and bind the ORM session to that connection instead of directly to the engine. You can also set default database at the user level, within the database (MODIFY USER).

Comment: Thanks for the help thus far @Fred. I think I am still missing something though . . . I have updated my driver to the most recent version available on Teradata's downloads page (TeradataODBC__macosx_x86_64.16.20.21.00.tar.gz). However, I am still getting the same 'QVCI feature is disabled' error when using teradata module to create the engine. It does look I can get around this error using teradatasqlalchemy module with the following connection string: ```python engine = create_engine(f'teradatasql://teradata-data.fyiblue.com/radar/?user={user}&password={pasw}&logmech=LDAP') ``` Continued....

Comment: However, I am not familiar with how I would set a default database at the connection level after creating the engine. . . and then binding it to the OEM session. Do you happen to have any resources/documentation to point me in the right direction for this? Thanks!

Comment: The general idea is `connection = engine.connect()` and then `result = connection.execute(f'DATABASE {myDBname}')` then explicitly use the `connection` object instead of just referring to the `engine` in the rest of your script.